# How do i replace decimal values with a specific value oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example i have these values :

```
9.0001
8.1556
1.0000
9.7345
2.0003
```

I want my result to be-

```
9.5
8.5
1.0
9.5
2.5
```

So any decimal value in the range (between 0.0001 – 0.9999) should change to .5

Comment: Are the values always going to be positive?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with only using the `floor()` and `ceil()` functions:

```
select floor(col) + (ceil(col) - floor(col)) / 2
from your_table
```

To see how this formula would work, consider the value `9.0001`:

```
floor(9.0001) + (ceil(9.0001) - floor(9.0001)) / 2
9 + (10 - 9) / 2
9 + 1/2
9.5
```

which is what you expected.  Also note that for `1.0000` the value would remain `1.0000` because the ceiling equals the floor in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are always to going to be positive, you can use this:

```
to_char(case trunc(x) = x then x else trunc(x) + 0.5 end, '99990D0')
```

if not, add a further case to do a subtraction or addition based on the sign.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try

```
SELECT ROUND(15.193,1) ...
```